# How to create a user in youtube?

Tags: youtube

I have been created webpage using php.

In my social links, I have been added subscribe links,

So i need to create `youtube` account, I m new about this section.

```
  <a href="http://youtube.com/">
                    <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
                    <span>Subscribe</span>
   </a>
```

I need something like this, `https://www.youtube.com/user/thegatesnotes` .. This is mentioned as example.

May i know, is it possible to create by myself?

Can anyone guide me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you just want to know how to make a Youtube account normally? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: yes sir.. @SpencerWieczorek ..

Comment: Then this isn't a programming question. Although creating a YouTube account is [pretty simple](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/161805?hl=en), if I understand you correctly.

Comment: already i have gmail account.. in this page what i have to do? thanks..

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: now i have been created like this https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChw8pyJGN0Gzc-ghgN_6SVA/feed .. here after, what to do .. thanks

Comment: So you created your account successfully?

Comment: I think, i doubted.. @SpencerWieczorek: because.. as i mentioned "https://www.youtube.com/user/thegatesnotes" like this.. so , how to i create like this https://www.youtube.com/user/SainaNehwal?

Comment: Are you there @SpencerWieczorek .. thanks

Comment: Look at the answer below, you need to satisfy requirements to get your own custom URL.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: I took a look below answer,,, but i just confused, to get custom url...

Comment: now i got look like this http://s4.postimg.org/4l3jl1gel/Untitled_1_copy.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Youtube's new policy](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657968?ref_topic=3024172&hl=en)

Eligibility requirements

To get a custom URL for your channel, your account needs to be in good standing and meet a few other requirements:

- <s>500</s> 100 or more subscribers
- Channels is at least 30 days old
- Channel has uploaded a photo for the channel icon
- Channel has uploaded channel art

You can also qualify for a custom URL by linking and verifying your official webpage with your channel or +Page.
Get a Custom URL for your channel

Once you’ve qualified for a custom URL, you’ll receive an email notification and a notification on your Creator Studio dashboard. To get your custom URL:

```
Sign in to YouTube and navigate to the Creator Studio.
Look for your “Get a new custom URL” notification and click in the included link
You’ll be redirected to claim a custom URL.
You’ll see the custom URL(s) you’ve been approved for. These cannot be changed. You may also need to add a few letters or numbers to make the URL unique to you.
Click the box next to “I agree to the Terms of Service” then click Change URL in the bottom left corner.
This URL will be linked to both your YouTube channel and your Google+ identity. Once your URL has been approved, you cannot request to change it. When you're certain, click Confirm choice.
```

Change capitalization or accents of your custom URL

If you want to change the capitalization or accents/diacritics of your custom URL, follow these steps:

```
Sign in to Google+. Place your cursor in the top left corner for the Google + main menu and then select the page or profile associated with your channel
Click the About tab, and under Links > Google+ URL, click Edit.
A box will appear allowing you to make edits to the formatting.
```

Remember, you can only change the capitalization and diacritics of the URL, not the URL itself.

Comment: Hi @pearl: i have been created channel and upload channel icon and channel art., still channel icon didn't change and my page look like this http://s11.postimg.org/yyeref2n7/Untitled_1_copy.png .. according to your answer, you mentioned "500 or more subscribers
Channels is at least 30 days old" so after getting those requirements only, I can create custom url right?..

Comment: Dear Sona you need to meet either of the 2 requirements  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
1) a)500 or more subscribers
    b) Channels is at least 30 days old
    c) Channel has uploaded a photo for the channel icon
    d) Channel has uploaded channel art

2) You can also qualify for a custom URL by linking and verifying your official webpage with your channel

Comment: Thanks @peral: I have raised two questions here, 1. Am i right, i created this link https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChw8pyJGN0Gzc-ghgN_6SVA ? and 2. If correct means, How can i earn 500 subscribtions?. Now i don't have official webpage.. Now i am working in localhost. After completing works, will have to host my page.. Thanks.

Comment: @sona  yes thats youtube channel url as of now . 

to earn subscriptions you have to promote your youtube channel and its not an easy process at all ... it needs that you upload new videos , the videos get lot of views and apart from that you can market your channel in facebook . Initially you can ask your friends to subscribe to your channel

Comment: hi @peral: now look like this, http://s4.postimg.org/cediy1dyh/Untitled_2_copy.png . but how do i know, who are all subscribed.. ? thanks

Comment: @sona - you can got this link to find your subscribers after logging into your account - https://www.youtube.com/subscribers .Note - *Only subscribers who share their subscriptions publicly are shown.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube Help at https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6180214 describes in detail the following three types of YouTube URL:

1.
ID-based URL
Example: youtube.com/channel/UCUZHFZ9jIKrLroW8LcyJEQQ
This is the standard URL that all YouTube channels use.

2.
Custom URL
Example: youtube.com/c/YouTubeCreators
A custom URL is a shorter, easy-to-remember URL...

3.
Legacy username URL
Example: youtube.com/user/partnersupport
Depending on when your channel was created, it may have a username. Usernames are no longer required for channels today...

So (as I can understand) it is not possible to create youtube.com/user/... now.